# Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] while running a roslaunch launch file

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Basically like the title refers on using this command:

```
roslaunch a1 a1.launch
```

This is the appearing the error in terminal :

```
while processing /opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/gmapping.launch.xml: Invalid roslaunch XML syntax: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: u'/opt/ros/kinetic/share/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/gmapping.launch.xml' The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

Of course I manually looked for the file and found it there in the normal directory, I checked my a1.launch file and my include syntax looks like in order aswel:

```
include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/gmapping.launch.xml"
```

It goes without saying that I am a complete amateur in all this, I've shown some interest in a robotics internship and am required to know basics and all.

Thanks in advance!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/263370/invalid-roslaunch-xml-syntax:-%5Berrno-2%5D-while-running-a-roslaunch-launch-file/) by [mavrec](https://answers.ros.org/users/30500/mavrec/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2017-06-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The repository shows that the file you are (probably) looking for is at a different path: you are missing a [gmapping/](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/blob/indigo/turtlebot_navigation/launch/includes/gmapping/gmapping.launch.xml) string in the `include`. So, in your `a1.launch` file you should change the line you have to:

```
<include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/gmapping/gmapping.launch.xml"/>
```

Instead of going to the repository online you could also use `roscd turtlebot_navigation` and find the path to the file you wish to include from your local filesystem.

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2017-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [mavrec](https://answers.ros.org/users/30500/mavrec/) on 2017-06-07**:
Works like a charm, thanks a lot!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-06-08**:
@mavrec: please accept the answer by @Thomas D by ticking the checkmark to the left of his answer.

**Comment by [ahumay](https://answers.ros.org/users/39906/ahumay/) on 2019-02-11**:
Does one have to re-compile after adding this (And how do you do that?). I added it but it doesn't seem to recognize the change.
EDIT: Disregard

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-02-12**:
@ahumay: so did it work for you in the end? If so: what did you change? Or was something else not working?

**Comment by [ahumay](https://answers.ros.org/users/39906/ahumay/) on 2019-02-12**:
@gvdhoorn yes, I just rebooted my machine